# polynomials- linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

$$\text{Let}\space K\space \text{ be a Field. let }F_{1},...F_{n} \text{be a Polynome over K with the property:}$$
$$\forall1 \leq i<j \leq n, \qquad \text{greatest common divisor of }(F_i,F_j)=1.
$$
$$
\text{Let}\space F=\prod_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}F_i \quad ,\text{and for} \space j\in\{1,...,n\} \space \text{let be } G_j=\prod_{i\in \{1,...,n\} \backslash\{j\}}F_i=F/F_j 
$$

$$
\text{show that there is a polynom}\space A_1,...,A_n \space \text{over} \space K \text{with the property: }
$$$$
1= \sum_{j\in\{1,...,n\}}A_jG_j 
$$

I've tried to answer it by saying that G_j could be rewritten as:
$$
G_j=\frac{F_i}{F_j}=\frac{1}{F_j\backslash\{i\}}
$$
And thus
$$1= \sum_{j\in\{1,...,n\}}A_jG_j=\frac{A_j}{F_j\backslash\{i\}}
$$
$$
 \lim_{j\to\infty} \sum_{j\in\{1,...,n\}}A_jG_j=\frac{A_j}{F_j\backslash\{i\}}=1
$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Look at references on "Partition of unity"

Comment: What do you mean by $F_j\setminus\{i\}$ for a polynomial $F_j$?

Comment: since $1 \leq i<j \leq n \implies F_i \subset F_j$
so $F_j\backslash \{i\} $ means $F_j$ without $F_i$

Comment: $F_j$ with $j\ne i$.

Comment: Hint: your conclusion holds if the $G_j$ are relatively prime.